# Search long varchar SQL

Tags: sql, database, search, varchar, ingres

I have a database in Ingres 9.2.0 that contains a long varchar column. Is there any way that I can search this column for a specific string and only return the rows that contain have that string in the column.

I tried using like as follows

```
select * from table
where col like '%abc%'
```

but I get the following error

> Function 'like' is not defined for arguments of type 'long varchar'
>   and 'varchar'. Explicitly convert its arguments to the desired
>   type(s).

---

I was able to resolve this with the following query

> select * from table
>   WHERE position('abc' in col) > 0

Comment: From `long varchar` sounds like maybe DB2? Please clarify this as the answer is dependant on which RDBMS

Comment: yeah you really have to provide more details dude.

Comment: It seems to be for Ingres: http://lists.ingres.com/pipermail/svn-commits/2009-January/001085.html

Comment: @ypercube - Seems you were correct!

Comment: @Stina which version of Ingres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for LIKE against LONG VARCHAR was added to Ingres 9.3.0 ([project page](http://community.actian.com/wiki/LIKE_Support_for_Long_Objects_Home) - If you have an earlier release this won't work.See the [feature list](http://community.actian.com/wiki/Ingres_New_Features_per_Release/Ingres_9.3.x_New_Features#DBMS_Server_Enhancements_2) for all 9.3 changes.

Comment: I have version 9.2.0, does that mean that the above query is incorrect? Thanks

Comment: If you get the error from the OP, then you *do not* have a version of Ingres which supports LIKE on LONG VARCHARs.

Comment: it was added in 9.3 not 9.2, I've updated the above text to reflect that.

Comment: @grantc thanks for your help, I have edited the question with the query that I used to resolve it.